# How to send a UTF-8 encoded strings via TcpSocket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, encoding, character-encoding

How to send a UTF-8 encoded strings via `TcpSocket` in Ruby? When I'm trying to use the following code

```
msg = $stdin.gets.chomp
@server.puts(msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

it gives me the "ASCII-8BIT" encoding on the server:

```
msg = client.gets.chomp
puts msg.encoding
```

Output

> ASCII-8BIT

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The data sent over the connection is just the raw bytes that make up the string, not the encoding that the client associates with them. The server therefore has no way to determine what the encoding should be and defaults to `ASCII-8BIT` which effectively means unknown.

If you know that the data will always be UTF-8 you can use [`set_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-set_encoding) on the socket to always mark the received data as the correct encoding:

```
client.set_encoding('UTF-8')
msg = client.gets.chomp
```

If it is possible that the data is in a different encoding from each client you will need to work out some protocol where the client tells the server what that encoding is before sending the actual data. The server can then use `set_encoding` as above, or use [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) on the resulting string.